# Pandas unable to access a json file in my Documents directory

Tags: python, json, pandas, permission-denied, kaggle

I am trying to run a demo of someone's script from Kaggle on my machine. The relevant line is:

```
traindf = pd.read_json("C:/Users/myUserName/Documents/input/train.json")
```

The error given is:

```
File "C:\SciSoft\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json.py", line 185, in read_json
with open(filepath_or_buffer, 'r') as fh:

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/myUserName/Documents/input/train.json'
```

I'm running on the only user on my laptop and this IS my laptop. There were no errors running this script on Kaggle.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have read permission on that file. You can just check it out by viewing the properties of that file. Other reason may be, due to other process holding write lock on that file. You can check it out by using Process-Explorer tool.